I can't buy my tokens in mainnet from another wallet
I can't buy my tokens in mainnet from another wallet.
The spl-token mint command returns the following error:
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, ProgramFailedToComplete)), logs: Some(["Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 0 of 0 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: exceeded CUs meter at BPF instruction"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) })
I reinstalled rust, reinstalled dev tools C++.
I've tried a lot, please help me//

I'm confused, are you buying tokens or minting them?

@JacobCreech I want to buy tokens, but this error is displayed

Can you give some code? Current it looks like you're trying to mint tokens.

@JacobCreech I am trying to buy tokens by first creating a token account with the following command spl-token mint 3PdqZD2j9Jj6r56YKj1vLigPo3aV9hRUaMwRhB5Ywbr9 10
Mining 10 tokens
Token: 3PdqZD2j9Jj6r56YKj1vLigPo3aV9hRUaMwRhB5Ywbr9
Recipient: 7Wgq46aJeGFq39myead2U72f4vAx9kbLBPqAobkw5yxy
Error: 

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of how tokens work on Solana here. You're trying to mint new tokens, not create a token account. Creating a token account is by doing spl-token create-account 3PdqZD2j9Jj6r56YKj1vLigPo3aV9hRUaMwRhB5Ywbr9 

@JacobCreech I want to buy tokens for solana using the token address. This token is already being traded. I previously created an account using spl-token create-account 3PdqZD2j9Jj6r56YKj1vLigPo3aV9hRUaMwRhB5Ywbr9.

It says you're minting the tokens afterwards. You have to interact with whatever market the token is on, not mint new tokens.

@JacobCreech Which command should I use to buy a token?

You cannot directly buy tokens using commands on the Solana network. The Solana command-line interface (CLI) is for interacting with the blockchain itself.
